# Vue.js: How to get attributes of an option in Select dropdown box?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom, v-model

If we bind a Select box values like the following Example:

```html
<select v-model="car">
 <option number="one">BMW</option>
 <option number="two">Audi</option>
 <option number="three">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

How can I get the value of the `number` attribute instead of the Name of the car in Vue.js?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `value` instead of `number` :

```
<select v-model="car">
 <option value="one">BMW</option>
 <option value="two">Audi</option>
 <option value="three">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

selected value will be assigned to `car` property.

**Example :**

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      car: ''
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <select v-model="car">
    <option value="one">BMW</option>
    <option value="two">Audi</option>
    <option value="three">Mercedes</option>
  </select>
  
  {{car}}
</div>
```